# Control width of text input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a single row with search inputs (a text input and an 'attached' button) at the left, and a button at the right (the bit above the grid):

[image: Sample of what I want]

Here's the code:

```
<form class="row form-inline">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input name="search" type="text" class="form-control input-sm">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="submit">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>  Search
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  Create
        </a>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem is that the width of text input is too small at the 'lg' and 'md' browser sizes, and only increases to something that looks OK when the browser is at smaller sizes. What's the best way to increase the width of the search input at larger browser sizes?

Comment: Define width interms of percetage, so that width will be large for browsers with large size.

Comment: May I know for what all devices your UI should support either lg/md/sm/xs?If you want to give support to ipad kind of devices then use sm,mobile device-xs etc.

Comment: @Archana only desktops, but I need the layout to work at both all browser window sizes (within reason, of course :)

Comment: @Cocowalla: Then please try with col-md-... instead of col-xs... Bootstrap will take care of responsiveness internally they have used media queries to support this

Comment: @Cocowalla: I have posted solution please have a look into it

Comment: try using media queries in css

Answer (score 0):

why dont you set the width on the input using bootstrap classes? e.g.

```
<input name="search" type="text" class="form-control col-lg-10 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any impact at all

Comment: Im guessing you are using bootstrap3 ive slightly updated my answer above but this is how its done.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 3, but I still get no change with your edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well

```
<form class="row form-inline">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input name="search" type="text" class="form-control col-md-6">
            <span class="input-group-btn col-md-2">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>  Search
                </button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" href="#">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  Create
        </a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Nope, that ends up looking a total mess, with controls split over lines and in different positions depending on browser window size

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in Bootstrap DOC form-inline require setting a width for input componentes:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

To solve that problem I have custom classes for that:

```
.input-width-X {width: X}
.input-width-Y {width: Y}
...
```

and use media queries for this classes in order to apply them just when you are not in XS mode, because Bootstrap set 100% width on it.

Sorry about my english :)